# ASP.NET WebAPI default landing page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've created a RESTful web service using ASP.NET WebApi v2 and I'm using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to generate swagger UI for API documentation.

All API calls are under http://localhost/api/ and the swagger UI page is at http://localhost/browser/index (the 'browser' part is configurable).

Browsing to http://localhost/ however will land on a empty page, so my question is is it possible to route http://localhost/ to http://localhost/browser/index so the user will be able to see the API documentation just by visiting the base uri.

One solution I can think of is to use a physical file system and create a static html page which does a meta fresh to redirect to the landing page I want, but I guess there must be a better way of doing this…

Comment: Can you not do a redirect in the controller, from the default page to the swagger page?

Comment: @KarlGjertsen I guess I can create a new controller just for this and route the default page..is it possible to achieve this without a dedicate controller?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change the route configuration `RouteConfig.cs`.

Instead of the default setting:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Change it to point at swagger:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Browser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Make sure you update `RouteConfig.cs` and not `WebApiConfig.cs`.

Comment: Consider the same scenario. But I have to redirect to  "http://localhost/browser/index.html" static html file. Is their any chance to make it ?

Comment: My Swagger URL: http://localhost:49952/swagger/ui/index
I changed RouteConfig.cs file like this:
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Swagger", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );