# How to include an start-page for an API written in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, global-asax

I inherited a rather undocumented Visual Studio API project with many subprojects, one of which is called `API`, and I assume what I am looking at is ASP.net.

[image: Project structure]

### Background

I have been working with APIs built with different different technologies and frameworks (perl, cgi, python, flask, just to name a few), but I am new ASP.net. 
After days of research I got the API running in Visual Studio (VS), and it also talks with the UI.

### Challenge

Since I have two *Startup Projects* in VS, two browser windows open-up when hitting *Start* in VS, the UI and the API. The UI does what it is suppose to do, but the browser with the API shows an HTTP 404 error like this

[image: 404 error]

This means that I might have various endpoints `/foo` and `/bar` defined, but not `/`. How do I do that? Ideally, it should give back a json with the name and the current version of the API-(sub)project.

### My approach up to now

I am missing the correct ASP.net search terms in order to solve the issue myself. I am even struggling to implement the workaround to serve a plain HTML file at `/`.  **Where in the project tree comes the `index.html`?** I tried the root folder, as well as a folder called `public`, but both does not work, I keep receiving the 404 error.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: This is probably a WebAPI project - .NET's implementation of RESTful web services.  It's not really intended to act like a web site - there's not really a concept of a start page.  You could look in the App_Start folder to see if there's a routes file, but it might be the default.  Alternatively, you could go to one of the controllers (for example, the HomeController.cs file should map to the /Home route.  I don't see an Area folder in the structure so it doesn't look like it has the built in help page.   Try googling C# WebAPI to get more information.

Comment: I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891721/ which describes how to change `RouteConfig.cs` so that it points to e.g. `localhost/swagger/ui/index` -- which was already around, as I just learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you created a file `index.html` located in the root directory, in order to get that shown as (sub)project start page, right-click on the project in the **Solution Explorer**, choose **Properties**. A new view will pop-up where you define the **Web > Start Action** to point to a **Specific Page** (rather than **Current Page**) where you enter `index.html`. Hit `CTRL+S` to save, and start the project.

[image: API Properies]

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here, for automatically documenting your endpoints.

1. Use the **HelpPage** which may be included with the Visual Studio project template
2. Install swagger by using the **swashbuckle nuget package**

If you go for the [option 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) then you will probably need to play around with with project templates and choose one that fits.  Then you should copy all of your existing code into the new project template.

[Swagger](http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/) seems to be more popular now so you should try that, especially if you are working on a modern code-base.  You can add XML comments to the controller endpoints and they will appear on your swagger page, `http:/localhost/swagger/ui/index`.  You will need to install the nuget package and follow the tutorial.

Comment: Your option 1 looks cool, but I am not sure how to do it. Option 2 seems even better, and I indeed there is already a `API\App_Start\SwaggerConfig.cs` with the minimal configuration. So the remaining issue is how to adjust the root endpoint `/` in a way that it points to the swagger page. May you help me with that as well, please?

Comment: If you go to your project properties you can set the default page to be the swagger endpoint.

Comment: Changing the project properties did the trick, I explained the steps in my own answer try.